# Error: object has no method wrap

Tags: jquery

chrome console error : object has no method wrap

```
$('.dropdown_menu_header_n').append($(this).children('div').clone().text().wrap('<a></a>'));
```

Please help i want to append a jquery Object text wraped with `<a></a>`

Answer (score 0):

`.text()` returns a string, not a jQuery object.  Also, `.wrap()` returns the original jQuery element, not the wrapped one.

Try this:

```
$('.dropdown_menu_header_n').append($(this).children('div').clone().wrap('<a></a>').parent());
```

Or if you want to wrap the contents, try `.wrapInner`:

```
$('.dropdown_menu_header_n').append($(this).children('div').clone().wrapInner('<a></a>'));
```

Comment: tnx 4 your answer Can I convert string to an Object?

Comment: @ShaD: What do you mean by "Convert string to an Object"?

Comment: @ShaD: Check my answer now, `wrapInner` might be what you want.

Comment: :Woooooow that going to work Tnx man .Can I remove <div></div> i tryed unwrap but thats not working

Comment: @ShaD: Try: `.wrapInner('<a></a>').find('a')`

Comment: wooooW thats what i want You are a Pro jQuery God :)