# jQuery .val() not working in Shadowbox

Tags: jquery, drupal, shadowbox

Using the answer from [Calling Jquery within / inside a Shadowbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13182875/calling-jquery-within-inside-a-shadowbox) *(thanks Rob Grzyb and kannan!)*, I was able to get my jQuery firing from within my Shadowbox on my Drupal site, however, I'm unable to get one part of it to function:

I have a form in my Shadowbox, and I'm using .val() to determine the value of the select field (and for testing purposes, displaying that value in an alert box).  When I click the 'Submit' button and the alert fires, the alert always reads the first value (Red) even though I've selected a different value (like Green).  On a regular page, it works as expected and the alert reads the correct value.

**Example code:**

```
<div class="color-form" style="display: none;">
  <h3>What's Your Favorite Color?</h3>
  <form class="color">
    <select name="colorurl" class="colorurl">
      <option value="red">Red</option>
      <option value="green">Green</option>
      <option value="blue">Blue</option>
    </select>
    <br />
    <input class="button" type="submit" value="Submit">
  </form>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function($){
      $('body').on('click', '.color .button', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var colorurl = $('.colorurl').val();
        alert(colorurl);
      });
    });
  </script>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
  jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $('a.form').click(function () {
      var thisContent = $('.color-form').html();
      Shadowbox.open({
        content: thisContent,
        player: 'html',
        displayNav: false,
        height: 350,
        width: 350
      });
    });
  });
</script>
<a class="form">Link to Form</a>
```

How can I modify this code so it works in the Shadowbox? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are duplicating the content when you create your shadowbox, so you have two copies of the dropdown. `val()` returns the value of the first element, which in this case is not the one in the shadowbox.

Try this:

In your code that sets up the shadowbox:

```
var thisContent = $('<div class="shadowbox-color-form"></div>').append($('.color-form').html())[0].outerHTML;
```

In the code that handles the click:

```
$('body').on('click', '.shadowbox-color-form .button', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var colorurl = $('.shadowbox-color-form .colorurl').val();
    alert(colorurl);
});
```

Comment: Thanks Jason!  That sounds like exactly what's happening.  However, adding `.wrap('<div class="shadowbox-color-form"></div>')` actually stops the Shadowbox from working, and I get a "has no method 'wrap'" javascript error.  I'm checking out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11534717/error-object-has-no-method-wrap, but not sure how that will work with my code just yet.  Will post if I get it working.

Comment: @areikiera I edited my answer. `html()` returns a string, which doesn't have a `wrap()` method.

Comment: it looks like the contents of div.color-form are loaded in the Shadowbox HTML, but not div.color-form itself, so I think that makes your solution not work.

Comment: That's perfect! Thank you so much for your help @Jason P! It's really amazing that people like you are willing to give of your time like this. Thanks a million!